# Clean URLs Broken after moving site to new host

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

I have copied an existing drupal 6 site to a new host. I thought it was an easy task. Just change the mysql login credentials and run. But obviously not. Fist page is up and runing, but all links to existing pages doesn't work.

What am I missing here? Another configuration I've missed.

The Drupal 6 installation is a NodeStream distibution.

Link to site:
http://u0002002.fsdata.se

Answer (score 1):

It is likely that you forgot to set up mod_rewrite so the nice urls don't work.

Answer (score 1):

It is almost certain mod_rewrite is not turned on you can access pages like this

http://u0002002.fsdata.se/?q=yrke-karriar

To resolve quickly:

1. Turn off clean urls (don't know the exact url in Drupal 6)
2. Flush all caches

This will resolve until you can get mod_rewrite turned on or working.

Answer (score 1):

A very common (and even easier to fix) problem that happens when moving hosts is that you forget to include the .htaccess file which can [cause problems with clean URLs](http://www.drupaldude.com/content/clean-urls-need-htaccess-file) too.

**Fix: Upload a fresh copy of the .htaccess file that comes with Drupal to your web root directory.**

> I have found out that sometimes I miss this file. This is because I installed Drupal by dragging all the files and folders over to my server, but since the .htaccess file starts with a period, OS X hides it. This means that the .htaccess file was never moved over. - Source [DrupalDude.com](http://www.drupaldude.com/content/clean-urls-need-htaccess-file)

And from Drupal.org directly, [Clean URLs not working? Check your .htaccess file](http://drupal.org/node/256410)

> Check if the .htaccess file was actually uploaded. It should be in the directory where you uploaded Drupal (for example: /public_html/drupal/)
>
> If the .htaccess file is missing, you need to upload it. If you accidentally deleted this file, just download Drupal again, and copy the new .htaccess file.
>
> Make sure the file is only called .htaccess and not htaccess.txt or anything else. The .period .at .the .beginning is required.
> This name usually means that the file will be invisible on folder listings on Unix-based systems so you might not always see it. If using an FTP client, you may have to configure it to 'show hidden files'. If listing on the commandline, you must ls -la to see it. This will be somewhat dependent on your OS.

Answer (score 0):

Here are two tutorials which may help you:

1. [How to move a Drupal site from one host to another](http://support.hostgator.com/articles/hosting-guide/publish-your-site/how-to-move-a-drupal-site-from-one-host-to-another)
2. [How to Move a Drupal Site to a New Host Without Going Crazy](http://www.juliakm.com/how-move-drupal-site-new-host-without-going-crazy)